# python dictionary creating keys on letters and values on frequency it appears

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to read text that looks like

```
TCCATCTACT
GGGCCTTCCT
TCCATCTACC
```

etc...

I want to create a dictionary, how can I read through this and set T, C, A, or G as the key and the values is the frequency that letter
appeared throughout the text?

Answer (score 4):

Simply pass the whole string to a [`collections.Counter()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and it'll count each character.

It may be more efficient to do so line by line, so as not to require too much memory:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter()

with open('inputtextfilename') as infh:
    for line in infh:
        counts.update(line.strip())
```

The `str.strip()` call removes any whitespace (such as the newline character).

A quick demo using your sample input:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> sample = '''\
... TCCATCTACT
... GGGCCTTCCT
... TCCATCTACC
... '''.splitlines(True)
>>> counts = Counter()
>>> for line in sample:
...     counts.update(line.strip())
... 
>>> for letter, count in counts.most_common():
...     print(letter, count)
... 
C 13
T 10
A 4
G 3
```

I used the [`Counter.most_common()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) to get a sorted list of letter-count pairs (in order from most to least common).

Comment: I'm receiving an error: ImportError: cannot import name 'Counter'